# Program that allows me to manage several computers remotely? (Similar to Soluto)?

Tags: windows-7, remote, administrator, remote-control, device-manager

I hope this question is acceptable to ask here on superuser. My eyes have just been open to the website application "Soluto", in which you can monitor and manage several (1 to 200) devices (Windows, Windows Server, iPad, and iPhones) remotely from your device. You can do all sorts of things, such as get Remote Access (similar to Remote Desktop Connection), and run a range of Soluto diagnostic tools that help you speed up the devices boot time, list all of the hardware and drivers on the device, all of the applications (and whether they can be updated), device crash support/solutions, etc.

I am wondering if there are other, maybe more robust, solutions out there besides Soluto that I can experiment with and use.

I just plan to use these on up to 10 or so devices (all family's and friends), so I'm not looking for anything for a business. But I would also like to know of any business oriented solutions too.

Please share any solutions you use, or know of, or any information that may help.

Thank you for any information!

Comment: Howdy! "I hope this question is acceptable to ask here on superuser." - Nope, check the [help](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).  We don't do product recommendations.

Comment: read: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software

Answer (score 0):

The business I work for uses Centrastage.

Very flexible, feature packed solution.

http://www.centrastage.com/

Comment: Can you try to develop your answer? Link only answers may go stale and force potential users to try and figure out if this solution is good for them. Read [this](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info.